# SVProgressHUD with Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I started my project with cocopods and wanted to test out. I created new project with a view controller and install pod SVProgressHUD. Then I created bridging header to use objective C code in Swift. I was able to build without any error, yet I couldn't see any result of using this framework on neither device or emulator.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        sleep(5000)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        })
    })
}
```

Any additional steps do I need to take in order to work with pods in Xcode 6? or just this framework is broken on iOS 8?

Comment: I think it's broken on iOS 8. The project hasn't gotten much attention in a year or two, ever since [the author's awesome public transit app](http://www.thetransitapp.com/) got really popular.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) shows signs of active development.

Comment: develompment on SVProgressHUD gained momentum lately and yes it works on iOS8